# Is this multiplication booth algorithm correct

Tags: verilog

```
module booth_multiplier(
    input signed [31:0] multiplicand,
    input signed [31:0] multiplier,
    input clk,
    input reset,
    output signed [63:0] product
);

    reg signed [63:0] product_reg;
    reg signed [31:0] recoded_multiplier;
    integer i;
    reg signed [63:0] extended_multiplicand;

    always @(*) begin
        // Booth multiplier recoding table
        for (i = 0; i < 32; i = i + 1) begin
            case ({multiplier[i], (i == 0) ? multiplier[0] : multiplier[i-1]})
                2'b11: recoded_multiplier[i] = 0;   // no adjustment
                2'b10: recoded_multiplier[i] = 1;   // +1 adjustment
                2'b01: recoded_multiplier[i] = -1;  // -1 adjustment
                2'b00: recoded_multiplier[i] = 0;   // no adjustment
            endcase
        end
    end

    always @(posedge clk or negedge reset) begin
        if (!reset) begin
            product_reg <= 0;
        end
        else begin
            // Sign extend multiplicand to match the width of product_reg
            extended_multiplicand = {{32{multiplicand[31]}}, multiplicand};

            // Add or subtract sign-extended multiplicand based on recoded multiplier
            case (recoded_multiplier)
                1: product_reg <= product_reg + extended_multiplicand; // Addition
               -1: product_reg <= product_reg - extended_multiplicand; // Subtraction
                default: product_reg <= product_reg; // No adjustment
            endcase
            
            // Shift product_reg to the left by one bit
            product_reg <= {product_reg[62:0], 1'b0};
        end
    end

    assign product = product_reg;

endmodule
```

I am trying to run a test bench for this code I created above for multiplication booth algorithm. I just want to make sure if this is correct because I am getting no wave forms. Maybe my test bench is wrong, I am not sure. I have been trying to figure it out but am just lost now lol.

Comment: Post the testbench

Answer (score 0):

The implementation does not produce correct output values because of timing and architecture problems.

It looks like you are using a single adder unit (actually a case statement in the synchronous process, not an instance of a module), which should take 32 clock cycles to complete a 32-bit (N = 32) mul.  However you don't have the appropriate control logic to split the functionality over 32 clocks.  The combinational for loop does all 32 iterations in one clock.

For what you have so far, the case statement is in a combinational process and will infer combinational logic. The for loop in the combinational logic will loop 32 times every clock cycle. During this process, the registers are only updated one time; at the end.
I think what you want (in this architecture) is for the case statement to loop one time per clock cycle so that the registers get updated as a result of each loop cycle/operation in the case statement.  So the entire algo should take 32 clocks to complete, the way the coding has been architected.
If you want to maintain this architecture:

1. Move the case statement to the clocked process.
2. Get rid of the for loop and use a counter to perform the same role the for loop is currently trying to accomplish.

In a larger perspective, you might be making this harder than it should by by using only one adder unit.  I searched this online and found simpler implementations of this using N adder units for N bit multiplies.  In your case that would be 32 adder units.  If you modify your code to use 32 adder units, then it seems like the result can be computed in one clock cycle using combinational logic.     To infer N adder units you will need N instances or a generate statement (looks like a for loop).  I would start with N instances.

Think of this as cooking hamburgers.
Your task is to cook 32 hamburgers.
You can cook 32 at a time, in which case you need 32 hamburger cooking machines or you can cook one at a time.
If you cook one at a time, you can't just dump salt 32 times on the first burger, wait one cooking time and say you are done (this is what you are doing now).  Rather
you have to salt1 cook1 wait1, salt2 cook2 wait2,....

Think about which architecture you want to build.
N instances (32 machines) seems simpler to me.

Whatever you build, think about how you want the registers to update on each clock cycle.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for the response. Sorry for getting back so late. I have taken your input and have made the following changes:

   1.  Moved the recoding of the multiplier to a clocked process.
   2. Introduced a counter to control the looping.
   3.  Removed the for loop and used the counter to perform the looping.
   4. Adjusted the case statements to operate on the current value of counter.

Comment: Glad the answer helped you.